# Name of tool for VB.NET documentation comments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, documentation-generation, xml-documentation

What is the name of the tool that allowed VB.NET code to have embedded documentation comments (corresponding to C# documentation comments) that could be extracted by this tool?

I am going through some old code; Visual Studio 2005 era. A trivial example is:

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
'''  <summary>
'''  Summary of Dispose.
'''  </summary>
'''  <param name="disposing"></param>
Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing Then                                                
        If Not (components Is Nothing) Then                          
            components.Dispose()                                     
        End If                                                       
    End If                                                           
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)                                        
End Sub
```

There was a 3rd party free (open source?) documentation generator tool that integrated into the Visual Studio menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It was [VBXMLDoc](http://vbxmldoc.tor-erik.net/), later renamed to VBXC. It has not been updated since 2006. It was freeware (not open source) and version 1.0 was supposed to be commercial (or shareware). But the last version was beta 3, still free. It is still possible to download beta 3. [Adding XML comments to the code](http://vbxmldoc.tor-erik.net/getting_started.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

Developers also used to use [nDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/). That might be what was used on your project. It's free and not Microsoft. It isn't used as much any more, as it isn't being maintained. And it's more oriented to C#. But there's at least [one VB helper tool](http://vb-doc.sourceforge.net/). These may not be what you'd want to use now, but they might correspond to the syntax of the comments embedded in your legacy code.

And there's another open source tool from Microsoft called [VBCommenter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBCommenter).

Comment: it could be the VB helper tool, http://vb-doc.sourceforge.net/. It does say it became obsolete with VB.NET 2005, but perhaps the old code was created under Visual Studio 2003 and not Visual Studio 2005 as I thought it was.

Comment: @Heidelbergensis I should think it was VS 2003. XML documentation was added directly to VB in VS 2005, see the what's new http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) - Not sure if it includes a VS plugin, but a quick Google search turns up a few tools like [DocProject](http://docproject.codeplex.com/) to integrate it.

Comment: This is a Microsoft tool, not a 3rd party tool. It is also from the middle of 2006.

Comment: I updated the link to the codeplex (open-source) site, which is more current.  It's not officially supported (effectively 3rd party), and you mentioned VS2005, so 2006 isn't out of the question (However there is a June 2010 release--Version 2.6.1062.1)

Answer (score 1):

Could be VSDocMan
URL: http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html